# Dimension of a tensor product of affine rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

The dimension of a ring is defined as the length of a longest prime chain as usual.

Let $A,B$ be affine rings over a field $k$.
Then $$\dim A\otimes_k B = \dim A + \dim B.$$
How can we prove or disprove this?

Comment: Thank you. We can use Noether Normalization. But how?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the easiest way to prove this uses Noether normalization. [See [this handout of Hochster’s](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/615W10/supNoeth.pdf).] To give more of a hint, you know that there is a polynomial subalgebra $k[T_1, \dots, T_n] \subseteq A$ over which $A$ is finite, where $n = \dim A$. Similarly, say $B$ is finite over $k[S_1, \dots, S_m]$. Can you write down an $(n + m)$-variable polynomial subalgebra of $A \otimes_k B$? Is $A \otimes_k B$ finite over this subring? Why is that enough?