# How to show $ \dim X \times Y = \dim X + \dim Y$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X, Y$ be affine algebraic sets inside $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$. 
I was wondering how can one show that 
$\dim X \times Y = \dim X + \dim Y$? Any comments are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The first step would be to translate this into a problem about $k$-algebras. The coordinate ring of $X \times Y$ is just the tensor product of the coordinate ring of $X$ and $Y$. Now your question is whether the dimension of $A(X) \otimes_k A(Y)$ is the sum of dimensions of $A(X)$ and $A(Y)$. That question is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191667/dimension-of-a-tensor-product-of-affine-rings).